# Is it possible to have Inline text with carriage returns after each element?

Tags: html, css

**Question:** How can I have elements `display:inline`but still have a carriage return at the end of each `span` or `a` element?

Caveats:

- No br tag
- must use display: inline
- undetermined width of elements

**HTML:**

```
 ...
    <hgroup>
      <span>{{splash.title}}</span>
      <span>{{splash.desc}}</span>
      <a ui-sref="principle" class="btn-primary">Enter</a>
    </hgroup>
```

**CSS:**

```
    hgroup {
      max-width: 360px;
    }
    span {
        font-weight: 300;
        color: $base-black;
        font-size: 3.75rem;
        display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to use spans instead of divs? spans are inline by default so you don't need to specify them to be inline. Why do you need the display to be inline and not block for the <a> element?

Comment: Yeah I know spans are by default inline.  I just did that for more display purposes.  a group of text to have width auto'd.  but I also want them to be vertically inline like list-items.

Comment: Is `white-space:pre-line;` (or `pre-wrap` or `pre`) on `hgroup` a viable option?

Comment: @Xufox just tried it doesnt give a return after every span

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Really? Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pofdkn6g/): works in Firefox 37.0.2.

Comment: I want them to display vertically down.  oddly white-space:pre-line worked on my js fiddle but not on my production.  I think it's flexbox

Comment: @Xufox it was a typo on my part.  Put answer I'll mark correct!  thanks.  I knew ther ewas a way in css.  Bit esoteric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answer featuring `white-space` is just as good here’s another option:

Instead of using a pseudo-class just style the `hgroup` with

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just tell it to in your CSS with a pseudo-class like this

```
span:after {
    content:"\000A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Good idea with the Line Break character in the pseudo class `content`!

Comment: Thank you, I like the fine grain control I get with this. I usually use this when I need to target a specific element. Usually with something like   span:nth-child(2):after

Answer (score 1):

Include `display:table-caption;` to the `span` class

```
span {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    display: inline;

    display: table-caption;
}
```